# Unable to get quickbooks connection ticket

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, qbxml

We have a Quickbooks online account and another application which connects with Quickbooks online using qbxml. We added a new company recently and need to get the connection ticket. But the connection ticket url : https://login.quickbooks.com/j/qbn/sdkapp/confirm?serviceid=2004&appid= seems to have stopped working. Could this be due to the deprecation of the qbxml api? Is there another way to get the connection ticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is deprecated, and new connections can no longer be established.

You have to use the new v3 REST APIs instead.

Comment: The deprecated API is working fine for the existing connections. Can you point me to any official page that says the new connections can no longer be established?

Comment: See https://developer.intuit.com/blog/2013/12/20/migration-details-quickbooks-online-sdk-to-quickbooks-online-rest-api-v3